# Windows Search issues

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I have this weird issue with one of our Windows 10 PC...  Search is no longer working.

Here is what I have done:

1. Stopped and restated **Windows Search** service.
2. Rebuilt **Indexing Options**.
3. Obviously restarted the PC.
4. Switched **Windows Search** from **Automatic (Delayed)** to **Automatic** under services.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Search issues  .....  Search is no longer working (Search rebuilt; services restart).

Try two things (at least initially).

**(A)  Run DISM / SFC and restart, test.**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(B) If (A) fails to correct, run Windows 10 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything

.

Keep Everything is the best starting point and hopefully that will correct the search issue.

Repairs get more aggressive after this (Keep only Data and reinstall Software; and Keep Nothing and start over).

Comment: Before I'd reinstall Windows, losing all files, I'd switch to a third-party search tool such as DocFetcher (indexed) or Agent Ransack (not indexed). Both offer more search options than Windows, as well.